# Dimension of the intersection of these two subspaces of polynomials, as depending on a parameter $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$V= \text{span}\{ 1+ax-2x^2,x+ax^2,2ax^2+x^3\}$$

$$W= \text{span}\{1+x-x^2,2ax-2x^2-x^3,(1-a)x+x^2\}$$

Find a basis for $V\cap W$ and determine its dimension for all values of $a$.

Can anyone guide me for this question?

Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

First check that those spanning sets (call them $[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ and $[w_1,w_2,w_3]$) are each linearly independent, so in fact *bases* of $V,W$ respectively, and this regardless of the value of$~a$. This is in fact the case; an easy way to see this is that for both spanning sets you can order the vectors (namely $v_2,v_3,v_1$ and $w_3,w_1,w_2$) so that each vector introduces a new power of $x$ (with nonzero coefficient) not yet occurring in the previous vectors.

With this out of the way, the dimension you are looking for is the number of independent linear relations between the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,w_1,w_2,w_3$. Indeed whenever one has coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that $av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dw_1+ew_2+fw_3=0$, one has $av_1+bv_2+cv_3=-dw_1-ew_2-fw_3$ which is a vector in $V\cap W$, and every vector in $V\cap W$ is so obtained for a *unique* set of coefficients (because we checked that $[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ and $[w_1,w_2,w_3]$ are bases of $V,W$. Comparing coefficients of individual powers of $x$ one can see that having such a linear relation is equivalent to $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ being solution of the linear homogeneous system with coefficient matrix
$$
  A=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&0&0&1&0&0 \\ a&1&0&1&2a&1-a \\ -2&a&2a&-1&-2&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&-1&0
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I looks like you are in luck, and can row-reduce this system without having to distinguish any cases depending on$~a$. When I do so, miraculously the final row becomes divisible by $1-a+a^2$ (which is a signature of a well-crafted exercise) namely it becomes $(1-a+a^2)(0~0~0~1~-2~1)$. Therefore $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\rk A=4$ whenever $1-a+a^2\neq0$, in which case $\dim(V\cap W)=\dim(\ker(A))=2$ by rank nullity. Indeed you can then choose coefficients $e,f$ freely, and solve $d$ from this final equation $d-2e+f=0$; the coefficients can also be solved using the first three (after reduction) equations, but you don't need to, since knowing $d,e,f$ suffices to find the vector $-dw_1-ew_2-fw_3\in V\cap W$. Indeed $(2e-f)w_1+ew_2+fw_3\in V$ (I've changed the signs) for all values of $e,f$, as you can easily check (checking the special cases $(e,f)=(1,0)$ and $(e,f)=(0,1)$ suffices).

The case $1-a+a^2=0$ leads to $\rk A=3$ so $\dim(V\cap W)=3$, which means that in fact $V=W$. This happens only if this was over the complex numbers (you didn't tell), in which case it happens for the values $a=\frac12\pm\frac12\sqrt3\mathbf i$.